# How much would it cost to replace HDMI port if it can be done separately

Tags: display, hdmi, port, tv

After the lightning struck my house, my PC doesn't recognize TV as a output, while TV recognizes HDMI input. Exhausting a lot of options here http://redd.it/2ribe7, I want to know would the whole motherboard have to go, or just a adapter/port.

Comment: Is there a DVI port?  Try a DVI-to-HDMI adapter.

Comment: Try searching HDMI OUT PC or even HDMI OUT PC ADAPTER at google.com, there are many many products out there for the purpose of adding HDMI out to a computer should you need to replace it.

Comment: That's what you buy insurance for. Lightning strike is the perfect opportunity to let them do what you pay them for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lightning strike will create a power surge and most likely you will have damage to at least some of the integrated circuits on the motherboard. While the port is more durable it too could be damaged.

You may also have other parts of the board damaged that you havent noticed yet. This can result in a unstable machine and other unexpected errors.

Provided you feel that you have ruled out other components as faulty, best solution is to just replace the whole board if you have the money to do so.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Nothing drastic, but noticeable.

Answer (score -1):

Add a graphics card, and you can bypass the Motherboard's Graphics Chip and HDMI port entirely.

It will probably work out cheaper than replacing the HDMI as you may also have to replace the GPU on the motherboard, if not more. Graphics cards can be purchased from around £30 for a basic one, but you should do some research to see what level suits your machine.

Comment: Whoever's downvoted, care to explain why?